# How can I start spyder python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I am having trouble starting spyder (I have installed Anaconda 64 bit version python 3.5). When I run spyder or spyder.exe in cmd I see the green logo of spyder but nothing happens afterwards, except that I get an error msg:

```
(C:\Program Files\Anaconda3) C:\WINDOWS\system32>spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(spyder.app.start.main())
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 103, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 154, in <module>
    from spyder.utils.environ import WinUserEnvDialog
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\environ.py", line 20, in <module>
    from spyder.widgets.variableexplorer.collectionseditor import CollectionsEditor
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\variableexplorer\collectionseditor.py", line 45, in <module>
    from spyder.widgets.variableexplorer.importwizard import ImportWizard
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\variableexplorer\importwizard.py", line 26, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import pandas.core.config_init
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config_init.py", line 14, in <module>
    import pandas.core.config as cf
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
```

**I am running Win 10 Pro 64bit**

Comment: Have you tried launching it first from Anaconda's Navigator? Spyder might not be installed yet and you may need to install it first in Navigator.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the Navigator first, but nothing happens. I get the green logo of spyder but that is it. The program never starts. That is why I tried the cmd start to get some error msgs.

Comment: Have you installed the 64bit version of Anaconda?

Comment: yes but I am running Win 10 pro 64bit. Shouldn't that be the right version ?

Comment: Try installing WinPython on your C: drive, and then run its Spyder:

<a>https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/files/WinPython_3.5/3.5.2.3/<a>

If it works, then the problem is in Anaconda.

Comment: That is on a folder directly on your C drive.

Comment: The winpython installation worked and I can now run spyder. 10x

Answer (score -1):

If you want to install Spyder directly, you need to follow these steps:

Install the essential requirements:

Python2.7+ or 3.4+
[PyQt5](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5) (recommended) or PyQt4

Install Spyder and its dependencies by running this command:

```
pip install spyder
```

For more read this :https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration

Comment: I have installed Anaconda, which installs both python 3x and spyder. I am having trouble with starting spyder not installing. 10x

Comment: May be you need to adjust the path in IDE.Or you can post issue here https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/anaconda

Comment: how can I adjust the path ?